# Sidebar and sticky footer

Tags: html, css

Seems I am a bit rusty on CSS today. Searched on stackoverflow, but most similar questions does not have any good answers.

In the code provided I want to add a *sidebar* inside the `#content` div. I also want the footer to stick to the bottom even if there is no text in the content.
Note that I do **not** want a `position:fixed;` footer. Just a footer that keeps at the bottom if there is no text on the page.

I tried making a sidebar by using the `float` property, but this cause the footer to not stick to the bottom.

How can I "divide" the content into two divs and make one of them a sidebar to the left.

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Arete/fzj5gLe6/1/)

This is what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

Comment: why don't you want a fixed position?

Comment: I want the footer at the bottom even if there is no content on the page. But I do not want it to be fixed at the bottom if the content text fills up the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the HTML structure as follow:

```
<header>
  <h1>Header</h1>
</header>

<main>
  <nav>
    <p>Sidebar</p>
  </nav>

  <content>
    <p>Content</p>
  </content>

  <footer>
    <p>Footer</p>
  </footer>
</main>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100vh;
}

header {
    background: LightSlateGray;
  max-height: 10vh;
    padding:10px;
}
  header h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
  }

main { height: 90vh; max-height: 90vh; }

nav, content, footer { display: inline-block; float: left; }
content, footer { width: 80%; }

nav { width: 20%; height: 100%; background-color: #ff9090; }

content { height: calc(100% - 200px); max-height: calc(100% - 200px); overflow: auto; }

footer {
    height:200px;           /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
  footer p {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

Demo link https://jsfiddle.net/fzj5gLe6/2/

Demo link that the content's text doesn't fill page: https://jsfiddle.net/fzj5gLe6/3/

### Edit 1 -

Revised CSS, some `max-height` are changed to `min-height`, in order to let the footer stick at the bottom, added `height: auto;` to make the `min-height` of `content` work, demo link: https://jsfiddle.net/fzj5gLe6/5/

```
html,
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100vh;
}

header {
    background: LightSlateGray;
  min-height: 10vh;
    padding:10px;
}
  header h1 {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px 0 0 10px;
  }

main { height: 0; min-height: 90vh; }

nav, content, footer { display: inline-block; float: left; }
content, footer { width: 80%; }

nav { min-height: 100%; width: 20%; }

content { height: auto; min-height: calc(100% - 200px); }

footer {
    height:200px;           /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
  float: right;
}
  footer p {
    margin:0;
    padding:10px;
  }
```

### Edit 2 -

To allow the `nav` element to fill the height, I have appended `position: relative;` to the `main` element, and also added clearfix fix to it to let the `main` to get the correct height of it inside elements. (also `height: auto;`)

```
main { position: relative; height: auto; }
  main:before, main:after { display: table; content: ''; }
  main:after { clear: both; }
```

After that I revised styles of the `nav` element as follow to make it fill the parent's height

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background:lightgreen;
  float: left;
}
```

Lastly, I make the `content` and `footer` elements to `float: right;` to complete the layout.

```
content, footer { float: right; }
```

Finished demo: https://jsfiddle.net/89ucrec5/3/

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to do this without using the `calc` property? I am worried about browser compatibility.

Comment: Uses percentage height for some element to abandoned the calc func, https://jsfiddle.net/fzj5gLe6/7/

Comment: You may also want to have a look at http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc , normally I would use jQuery instead CSS to improve compatibility for such unusual requirement.

Comment: I tried this out and added some content text. The problem now is that the sidebar does not stretch down to the bottom of the screen. https://jsfiddle.net/Arete/89ucrec5/

Comment: Thanks for the effort here. This works visually, but since this `vh` is not supported in IE8 and older android phones I am afraid I can't really use it. I guess I should have included that browser compatibility is an issue in the question. Oh well...

Comment: why not go with some javascript?